# Use self signed certificate for communication between web app and web api on different server

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssl, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with communication between my web application and web api.
It worked OK when I did not enfore HTTPS.

The thing that does not work for me is related to my self signed SSL certificates.
When I access either of them through a browser, I get the warning about a certificate and I can add it to exceptions and view the page fine.

However, when its a communication between the web app and web api, I simply get this error at POST method in the web app (the caller).

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)`

Now, the way I have set up my certificates.

On web app server I have added a certificate in IIS manager and then set a binding for the page to use https and this certificate.
On the web api server, I've created another certificate and bound it to the page.

I tried exporting the certificate from web app as pfx file and copying it to the web api server. I have then used iis manager to import a certificate, I have also used MMC certificates snap in (certlm) to import the certificate from web app - I have put it in Trusted Root Certification Authorities, then in Third Party Root Certification Autorities and finally into Personal container - still the same issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, most likely when we move these into production, they will be hosted with a 'normal' 3rd party SSL certificate, so I suppose I would not see this issue if it wasn't for self signed one?

Cheers!

Comment: That's right, you won't see the issue in production when using an appropriate certificate. The reason you see it now is that the web app receives back the warning page and cannot bypass it like you did when you manually added it to the exceptions. It is complicated to get a self-signed certificate trusted, so I recommend to only enforce SSL for production.

Comment: Use Let's Encrypt certificates if you can. They are now simpler than self signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a DEV ONLY workaround by registering a global validation callback as below. 
Notice that it basically hardcodes validation to true, which can be a security issue.

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`

In my case, I've made it configurable -  by default this callback is not registered unless specifically configured to do so.